# learning maths for statistics

Tags: statistics, education, learning

Apologies if I have posted this in the wrong place first off.

My work has taken me into a unexpectantly large amount of statistics. In order to really understand what I am doing I need to understand these statistical approaches. However it seems almost impossible to do that unless you speak math (I don't as I'm sure you can tell).

So my question is are there any free online resources for learning/ getting familiar with terminology, symbols, concepts commonly used in maths/statistics that are aimed at people with basic math skills (basic algebra is okay, can barely remember how to differentiate).

Thanks in advance,
Cheers,
Davy

Edit to say:
I should mention that I am somewhat (not very) familiar with basic concepts like variance, hypothesis testing, and regression, but only on a practical level. I want understand these on the mathematical level on which they were built. Method development is something I am interested in, but I'll never be able to do, If I don't start learning more mathematics. MY problem thus far seem that every book on statistics assume you don't want to see any maths at all, or your totally familiar with giant equations, which are therefore, not explained well to someone who has no idea what (probably) commonplace symbols mean. I guess what I am really looking for is an induction to the domain specific language of maths, with a view towards stats.

Comment: Thanks to Kirthi Raman. Downloading all of UC berkeley iTunes U statistics collections.

Comment: It looks like an introductory text on probability or statistics would be better for you.

Comment: @Davy did you know that you could choose the answer as accepted answer by clicking on tick mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best online courses are offered by OCW (MIT). However, for Statistics you should look at Stanford's Courses on iTunes.  The best place for Statistics is UCBerkeley and Stanford. You may also check www.statistics.com (online courses- not free).